# Regexp in pipes instead of slashes?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Most PHP docs show regexps wrapped in slashes like:

```
preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $str );
```

I was looking in the source of WP's [formatting.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/formatting.php) and saw some regexps wrapped in pipes instead of slashes. How does the behavior of wrapping in pipes differ from wrapping in slashes? Is there any functional difference? Some examples in that file are:

```
preg_replace( '|\s+|', ' ', $str ); # consolidate whitespace

preg_replace( '|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '', $str ); # remove octets
```

Comment: `When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character. ` http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: It's just a matter of taste IMO, although sometimes it's easier if there are slashes in your pattern and you don't want to escape them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-slash delimiters, like the pipe character, make it easier to match for slashes, because you don't have to escape them.

```
preg_replace( '|/+|', '/', $str );  # collapse consecutive slashes in path
```

Comment: Well awesome. Had no idea. my... mind is kinda blown. Sucks that PHP.net documentation isn't more consistent with their syntax.